# ‘Not so beautiful’ vs 'less beautiful'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What I want to say is that the not so beautiful girls are less bothered by boys, and hence are more likely to succeed in studying.

> Girls not so beautiful are more likely to succeed in studying.

versus

> Less beautiful girls are more likely to succeed in studying.

Are both sentence correct in grammar?

Answer (score -1):

Both look correct however the first should have been

```
Girls, who are not so beautiful, are more likely to succeed in studying.
```